# HTML: Textarea does not return the value

Tags: html

I'm having a problem with textarea; in particular I don't get back the "description" value saved in the database. I just get a blank, worthless space.

I have name and price which are of type text, while description is textarea, as the code below shows.

```js
Name:              <input type="text" name="name" value="${fruit.name}" />
        
Descrption:       <textarea class="text" name="description" rows="4" cols="50" value="${fruit.description}"> </textarea>

Price:            <input type="text" name="price" value="${fruit.price}" />
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

textarea should be like this

`<textarea class="text" name="description" rows="4" cols="50"> ${fruit.description}</textarea>`